# When Video plays using AVPLayer, it stops background music ios

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am playing video using `AVPlayer`, it stops iPhone's music which is on going in background. Please help me to resolve

```
let item1 = AVPlayerItem.init(URL: NSURL(string:path))
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item1)
layer?.player = player;
player?.play()
```

Comment: the music comes from another app like the music app or something?

Answer (score 56):

My movies are for animations; they have no sound. To let other sound continue playing, in Swift:

```
    // None of our movies should interrupt system music playback.
    _ = try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
```

Thanks to Marcus Adams for the original answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use a [category for the AVAudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories) that allows mixing, such as `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` and add `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`.

From the docs:

> - AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
>
>   Mixes audio from this session with audio from other active sessions.
>
>   Valid only if the session category is
>     AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord or AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback.
>     (Implicit if the session category is AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient.)
>
>   If you activate your session while using this option, your app’s audio
>     will not interrupt audio from other apps (such as the Music app). If
>     not using this option (or a category that is implicitly mixable),
>     activating your session will interrupt other nonmixable sessions.
>
>   Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 11):

In swift 4.2 Please try this one.

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options: .mixWithOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
   } catch {
        print(error)
   }
```

Comment: its not a 4.2, i guess. Because of AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback it looks like swift 4.0 or something

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/playing_audio_from_a_video_asset_in_the_background

If you want to continue playing audio, you disconnect the AVPlayer instance from the presentation when entering the background and reconnect it when returning to the foreground.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

     // Disconnect the AVPlayer from the presentation when entering background

     // If presenting video with AVPlayerViewController
     playerViewController.player = nil

     // If presenting video with AVPlayerLayer
     playerLayer.player = nil
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
     // Reconnect the AVPlayer to the presentation when returning to foreground

    // If presenting video with AVPlayerViewController
    playerViewController.player = player

    // If presenting video with AVPlayerLayer
    playerLayer.player = player
}
```

Eg for your ViewController using `AVPlayer`

Step : 1

Enable Background mode In Capabilities for Audio, AirPlay, and Pictures in pictures

Step : 2

AppDelegate.swift

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: .mixWithOthers)
        print("Playback OK")
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("Session is Active")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Step : 3

YourViewcontroller.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPlayerNotifications()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    removePlayerNotifations()
}

 func addPlayerNotifications() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillEnterForeground), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}

func removePlayerNotifations() {

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)
}

//App enter in forground.
@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ notification: Notification)        {

    yourPlayerLayer.player = yourplayer

}

//App enter in forground.
@objc func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ notification: Notification) {

    yourPlayerLayer.player = nil

}
```