# What should I do playing AVPlayer video in my app with user's iTunes music?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer

I have a video without music, I want to show user even if music playing in the another app. My below code interrupt video playing if music playing.

In view controller:

```
    if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "streamVideo", ofType: "mp4") {

        print("handled video: \(filePath)")
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL as URL)

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        avPlayer.volume = 0
        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none

        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(FirstVC.playerItemDidReachEnd),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                               object: avPlayer.currentItem)

        avPlayer.play()

    }
```

In app delegate:

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513947/when-video-plays-using-avplayer-it-stops-background-music-ios which has the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/39084300/22147

Comment: @RhythmicFistman No this is different question. My music continue playing, but video doesn't play.