# IOS: AVAudioSession not working

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I am trying to use AVAudioSession, but it is throwing this runtime error:
`[avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields:Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type Speaker)`. If it helps I am trying to just record audio, and monitor the current decibels. I set the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord`, and the mode to `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement`.
here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var recording = false;
    var ready = false;

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    @IBOutlet public weak var dBLabel: UILabel!

    func alert(title: String, message: String = "", handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Swift.Void)? = nil) -> Void {
        var usedMessage: String
        if(message.characters.count < 1) {
            usedMessage = title;
        } else {
            usedMessage = message;
        }
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: usedMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: .default, handler: handler))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func checkPermission()
    {
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
        {
        case .authorized:
            NSLog("Authorized for Microphone Use")

        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, completionHandler: { granted in
                self.checkPermission()
            })

        case .denied:
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Denied Access to Microphone", message: "You denied access to the microphone, please enable access in settings", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default, handler: { _ in
                guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
                    return
                }

                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    })
                }
            }))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel"), style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        case .restricted:
            alert(title: "Restricted",message: "You cannot enable the microphone, so you cannot use the app", handler: { _ in
                NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
            })
        }
    }

    @IBAction func toggleRecord(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if(!ready)
        {return}

        NSLog("Toggled Recording")
        recording = !recording;
        if(recording)
        {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MicIconHighlighted.png"), for: .normal)
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MicIconHighlightedSelected.png"), for: .highlighted)
            //captureSession.startRunning()
            do
            {
                try audioSession.setActive(true)
            } catch {
                NSLog("Activating AudioSession Failed")
            }
        } else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MicIcon.png"), for: .normal)
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MicIconSelected.png"), for: .highlighted)
            //captureSession.stopRunning()
            do
            {
                try audioSession.setActive(false)
            } catch {
                NSLog("Deactivating AudioSession Failed")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        checkPermission()
        do
        {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        } catch {
            NSLog("Setting category on AudioSession failed")
        }

        do
        {
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        } catch {
            NSLog("Setting mode on AudioSession failed")
        }

        do
        {
            try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
        } catch {
            NSLog("Failed Setting Audio Output Data Source")
        }


        //NSLog("debug info: \(audioSession.outputDataSources!.count)");

        /*captureSession.beginConfiguration()
        let audioDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput
        let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio)
        if(audioDevice != nil && (audioDevice?.isConnected)!) {
            NSLog("Audio Device Name: \(audioDevice!.localizedName)")
        } else {
            NSLog("AVCapture Device default audio device failed or device not connected")
        }

        do {
            audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
        } catch {
            alert(title: "Failed to create Capture Device",message: "Failed to create Capture Device", handler: nil)
            return
        }

        if(captureSession.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput))
        {
            captureSession.addInput(audioDeviceInput)
        } else {
            alert(title: "Failed to Add Input",message: "Failed to add Audio Input Device", handler: nil)
        }

        let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        var audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder()
        audioRecorder.
        var audioQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioqueue", attributes: .concurrent)
        audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(AudioOutputSampleBufferDelegate(vc: self), queue: audioQueue)
        NSLog("Current Queue: \(audioOutput.sampleBufferCallbackQueue.description)")
        if(captureSession.canAddOutput(audioOutput))
        {
            captureSession.addOutput(audioOutput)
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        } else {
        alert(title: "Failed to Add Output",message: "Failed to add Audio Output Device", handler: nil)
        }*/

        ready = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be most helpful if you shared the code where you set your AVAudioSession parameters

Comment: I updated it to include the category and mode

Comment: Try to change AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord

Comment: It is still giving that error. The thing is, I set it up(with the settings above) and set it active, but I don't do anything other than that. I don't even need playback functionality. I tried using an AVCaptureSession as well, and it gave the same error

Comment: Have you tried reducing your app to just your audio initialization code? If so, maybe you could share the actual code with us.

Comment: I added the view controller. It has my current code, as well as left overs from my attempt at an AVCaptureSession-based system

Comment: The code you pasted works for me.  Created a brand new Swift project, set swift version to 3.2; added Info.plist key for Microphone usage, added "Toggle Record" button and set its action to toggleRecord; logs shows "Toggled Recording", no crashes, no other errors.  FYI tested on iPhone 7Plus

Comment: I have been trying it on an actual device(iPhone SE). That might contribute to the problem, but I am developing it for in-house, with one user who has an iPhone SE, so I have to get it to work on one.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a iPhone SE to test with.  All I can say is your code runs properly on iPhone 7Plus.

Comment: Alright, Thank you for your (quick) help

Comment: Something else to consider, iOS version.  I did my testing on latest iOS 11; your mileage may vary with older iOS releases.

Comment: I just realized I am running the IOS 12 beta, so that is probably causing the problems

Comment: iOS 12b12, I am also seeing these warnings/errors ~!!!

Comment: I am seeing the same error in official iOS 12 release and official XCode 10. Any inputs on how to fix it?

Comment: Swift 4.2 doesn't even allow "setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)", and with a suggested fix found here, I am now getting the error in the console "Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker" and my app crashes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010390/avaudiosession-setcategory-swift-4-2-ios-12-play-sound-on-silent

Comment: I use AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient and see the same warnings.

Comment: I am also seeing these warnings/errors. iOS 12.

Comment: any solution yet ?

Comment: I am also seeing this flood of "[avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields:". But in swift app that has nothing to do with audio.

Comment: Same here with AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient and Objective-C

Answer (score 5):

AVAudioSession has some changes in Swift 4.2

under viewDidAppear(), try this:

```
    // Prepare Audio Session
    self.audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .measurement, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

It worked for me when I converted the language to Swift 4.2 in Xcode 10
You can do that by going to...

> Edit, Convert, To Current Swift Syntax...

Comment: Great. This worked for me. I still get the error : "AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)". But after adding  try audioSession.setActive(false, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)  the audiosession is properly de-activated and any other audioSession resumes playing.

Answer (score 0):

Paste in viewWillAppear()
AVAudioSession has some changes, the corrected Syntax for Swift 5.0
Declare  var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!

```
recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try recordingSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .spokenAudio, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
            try recordingSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if allowed {
                        self.loadRecorder()
                    } else {
                        // failed to record!
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // failed to record!
        }`
```