# AVAudioPlayer throws when initializing with M4A file. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, core-audio

I am trying to initialize and play an `AVAudioPlayer` from a URL that contains an M4A file. The file is below:

https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview123/v4/e8/04/59/e80459fb-9429-3323-4f43-ce12d5df1be5/mzaf_5785529815715338950.plus.aac.p.m4a

Here is the code I am using to initialize said AVAudioPlayer:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer!
let preview = "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview123/v4/e8/04/59/e80459fb-9429-3323-4f43-ce12d5df1be5/mzaf_5785529815715338950.plus.aac.p.m4a"

func loadAudio() {
    do {
        self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: preview!)!, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.m4a.rawValue)
        self.player.play()              
    } catch let error {
        print("Error:", error.localizedDescription)                              
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    loadAudio()
}
```

When pressing the button associated with that `IBAction` named `buttonPressed(sender:)`, I am receiving the following error:

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)`

I have tried troubleshooting with similar questions regarding this error, but none seem to resolve my issue.

**Edit:**

I tried doing something similar with `AVPlayer` and, while it didn't throw an error, the file simply didn't play. Here is some sample code:

```
var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
let preview = "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/AudioPreview123/v4/e8/04/59/e80459fb-9429-3323-4f43-ce12d5df1be5/mzaf_5785529815715338950.plus.aac.p.m4a"

func loadAudio() {
    if let url = NSURL(string: preview!) {
        self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
        self.avPlayer.volume = 1.0
        self.avPlayer.play()
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    loadAudio()
}
```

Comment: AVAudioPlayer doesn't play remote files. You want an AVPlayer.

Comment: I tried doing something similar with `AVPlayer` and the player simply didn't play when I called `player.play()`. I could add some code if that is useful. @matt

Comment: I don't see why that would be useful. I changed your code to use an AVPlayer and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. My phone was on "silent mode" when running this code. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010390/avaudiosession-setcategory-swift-4-2-ios-12-play-sound-on-silent) I needed to add

```
do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
    }
    catch {
        // report for an error
    }
```

before actually plying from the AVPlayer.

The reason this problem hadn't crossed my mind was because when looking at the music manager in my iPhone's Control Center, there was no indication of audio being played. **Just because audio is being played doesn't mean that playback controls are being handled by the device's Control Center.**

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayers don't play remote content. Use an AVPlayer.

```
var player: AVPlayer!
let preview = ....

func loadAudio() {
    self.player = AVPlayer(url:URL(string: preview)!)
    self.player.play()
}
```

Comment: See the edit I've made. I tried using `AVPlayer` and the audio simply doesn't play. It is important to note, I am actually calling this function in `viewDidLoad()`, I simply placed it in an `IBAction` for this example to simplify things.

Comment: My code, running in the simulator, plays the file at the URL you gave. I tap the button, the noise plays. That's really all there is to know about that.

Comment: I appreciate the input. I'll let you know if I can get this working.