# Make AudioServicesSystemSound play even on silent using kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a camera app. I want to create a custom camera click sound, and have it always played when a photo is captured.

Apple's documentation of [kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/kaudioservicespropertyisuisound) says that setting the value to 0 should allow the System Sound to play regardless of the user's preferences.

Note that I am not trying to [do this via AVAudioSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010390/avaudiosession-setcategory-swift-4-2-ios-12-play-sound-on-silent), because that sound is affected by the user's volume setting. The goal is for this to be a System Sound via AudioServicesSystemSound.

With the following approach, the system sound plays when the phone is not on silent, but it does NOT play when the phone is on silent.

```
let customSoundUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cameraclick", withExtension: ".wav")!
var customSoundId : SystemSoundID = 0
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(customSoundUrl as CFURL, &customSoundId)
var flag: UInt32 = 0
let err = AudioServicesSetProperty(kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound,
                                   UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: customSoundId)),
                                   &customSoundId,
                                   UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: flag)),
                                   &flag)
```

Am I incorrectly setting the value of kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound? Or am I misinterpreting Apple's documentation, and is it actually not possible to play a System Sound even when the device is on silent?

Comment: hitting the same issue, have you found a solution? Maybe the behavior was changed in some iOS release